Identifier on yearly base
I want a monotonic increasing identifier for each year, starting with 1 on each year. There could be  rows with NULL in BusinessKey column. I'll call the function in an INSERT trigger:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Test];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  [Year] [int] NOT NULL,
  [BusinessKey] [int]
)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([Year], [BusinessKey]) VALUES
(2024, 1),
(2024, 2),
(2024, 3),
(2024, NULL),
(2024, NULL),
(2025, 1),
(2025, 2),
(2025, NULL);

-- Make a hole (gap) in the id column
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Test] WHERE [Id] = 2
GO

SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Year] ORDER BY [Id]) AS BuisnessKeyCalculated
FROM [dbo].[Test]

Which gives:



Id
Year
BusinessKey
BuisnessKeyCalculated
Expected




1
2024
1
1
1


3
2024
3
2
3


4
2024
NULL
3
4


5
2024
NULL
4
5


6
2025
1
1
1


7
2025
2
2
2


8
2025
NULL
3
3



Does anybody know how to solve that with window functions?

ISNULL(BusinessKey, MAX(BusinessKey) OVER(PARTITION BY Year) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Year] ORDER BY case when businesskey is null then 0 else 1 end, [Id])) AS BuisnessKeyCalculated might work, although not sure it handles multiple "pockets" of NULLs

So you only want to use business key if it is null, otherwise an auto number value?

I simplified: I will assign the new businesskey in an INSERT TRIGGER. So, the rows will be there with businesskey = NULL and I will join it with "inserted", so that i don't update already set businesskeys

What if there are gaps in some of the years? example 2024 has also BusinessKeys 6 and 7 ?

The only scenario i can think of: somebody deleted some rows. But if a new row was added, its imo save to get the MAX id and add new ones (as the answer shows). Do you see any other scenarios?

The following seems to produce the expected result:
select *, coalesce(
  businesskey,
  count(case when businesskey is null then 1 end) over (partition by year order by businesskey, id) + 
  max(businesskey) over (partition by year)
) as expected
from t

The count() over () trick assigns increasing row number to null values. The max() over () adjusts those row numbers.
